# Chrome apk is failed to install in android emulators

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I just tried the following things, first I tried to start the adb server using the below commands

Navigate to platform-tools folder:

adb start-server, and checked the adb devices and It returns connected emulator devices. and then I tried to execute the install command as below:

adb -e install pathtoapkfile. It doesn't returned anything, and I'm not sure whether It's installed or progress or any issue happen. the apk file doesn't exceed 40mb.But I waited the whole day, nothing observed. The command line shows nothing about the installation process.

Can somebody help me out.

Comment: Also I tried to kill the adb server and start it again. but no luck.

Comment: Goto DDMS In left side Device option there , In that tab right side , View Menu Option , Click on that and select Reset adb. Then you will be get solution.

Comment: Yes. Its fixed the issue. thanks pans.